# Find Delete Duplicates based on field - SQL - Delete the oldest based on TIMESTAMP field.

Tags: sql

Ok so I have a table which stores prices and eventdetails.

All the details will be the same apart from the UPLOADDATE which will be different (When the prices were uploaded) - I want to delete the old prices.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1db0e/1

Thanks

Comment: when you say you want to delete the old prices, you mean `the old prices for each X`. What table and column should replace `X`there? PS: Remember to accept previous answers

Comment: Hi Mosty, thanks for the tip. The table is wp_events and delete the full row based on the query. So there are 2 rows both have the exact merchant, event details but the only difference is the upload date.. So delete the oldest row

Answer (score 0):

Try running this query:

```
select e1.* from wp_events e1
left join wp_events e2
on e1.merchant = e2.merchant and e1.uploaddate < e2.uploaddate
where e2.uploaddate is not null
```

If it returns the result you're looking for, then execute the delete by replacing just the first line:

```
delete e1 from wp_events e1
left join wp_events e2
on e1.merchant = e2.merchant and e1.uploaddate < e2.uploaddate
where e2.uploaddate is not null
```